# Advanced Windows Firewall - Strange logging behavior

Tags: firewall, logging, group-policy

I have created a GPO that set's several firewall rules to Windows Server 2008 R2 machines within a specific OU. The default behavior is set to block on inbound and outbound on all profiles. Also I did enabled logging for droped packets.

So far everything works as expected, however the logging mechanism seems to log only specific drops. If I use my poor-mans scanner telnet and try to connect to the server on a nonexistent and blocked port like 55555 i do not see any drops within the log.

How comes? Pulling my hair here...

Comment: Logging is usually enabled on a per-profile basis as well, are you sure you haven't just enabled logging for one profile?

Comment: I have triple-checked that...